# Input needed for balancing SQL Server write performance against read performance

Tags: sql-server

I've got a service running that transforms data and writes the transformed (a couple of million rows) data to a SQL Server. The frontend reads from these tables.

Naturally, we've got an ambition to have this data written as fast as possible, but without sacrificing read performance.

My current approach is writing individual rows, one server call at a time. This seems to minimize locking, but the write speed is not optimal. Unthrottled we're achieving maybe a couple of thousands of rows per second.

I've also attempted to bulk load the data, but I run into deadlocks and timeouts. I'm assuming this is due to lock escalation when inserting/updating (i batch the commits in chunks of 256 rows).

Any ideas for a faster way to commit the records to database without sacrificing read performance?

Some details:

- The transformed data resides in a number of different tables, all indexed to maximize read performance.
- I use a single, continually open, connection to write the data.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes you are on SQL Server 2008+, but if you are, then I would look at using a stored procedure that accepted a table-valued parameter. You could then call that procedure with whatever batch size you wanted, and the locks would only be kept for the duration of the time it took to insert those rows. When you're running a bulk copy locks are kept for the duration of the copy, so making changes to the batch size doesn't have a major effect on lock duration (except, of course, for changes to the overall bulk copy time).

I wrote a blog post with a helper class for submitting data as TVPs easily [here](http://www.atlantis-interactive.co.uk/blog/post/2011/05/21/A-generic-list-for-passing-table-valued-parameters-to-SQL-Server.aspx). And you can read up about creating procedures with TVP parameters on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx). It's also worth reading Bob B's blog articles which are [here](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/BOBB/post/The-interesting-case-of-TVPs-and-plan-compilation.aspx) and [here](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/BOBB/post/TVPs-and-plan-compilation-the-reprise.aspx) (also referenced in my blog post).